# How to restrict API endpoints which are deployed in AWS Application Load Balancer?

Tags: security, deployment, aws, load-balancing

I created one webapi application which includes few modules like account, user etc and overall includes 10 or more endpoints.

I deployed this in EC2 instances and configured in application load balancer with domain in cloud front. The authentication used is oauth2 (bearer token)

All working fine and can access using domain address and load balancer address. As this can access from anywhere and can register to the application using register API. So how can I restrict this.

How can I restrict this public access? Which is the standard practice for this deployment?

Comment: Do you mean like with a firewall?

Comment: what kind of restrictions are you looking for? Restrictions on who can access the service, restrictions on who can sign-up, something else?

Comment: Basically I don't want  any public to access this endpoints. Only my clients can use these endpoints and register as a user and can use by getting token

Comment: Take an example the API can access by www.myhost.com/api/register. Only clients which we allowed only can use these APIs to register as a user. No one can use this.